# uWSGI doesn't switch to defined user uid=my_user in custom uwsgi.ini file

Tags: python-3.x, uwsgi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am running `uwsgi 2.0.17.1`, `nginx/1.12.2` and `flask 1.0.2` to run a custom  API on `Centos 7`. Everything works perfect except that the processes are owned by the `uwsgi` user while I explicitly defined in my custom `.ini` file to use a different user than `uwsgi`
This is the default `uwsgi` ini file located in `/etc/uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
uid = uwsgi
gid = uwsgi
pidfile = /run/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
emperor = /etc/uwsgi.d
stats = /run/uwsgi/stats.sock
chmod-socket = 660
emperor-tyrant = true
cap = setgid,setuid
```

And this is the content of my custom .ini file

```
[uwsgi]

chdir = /var/www/my_api/current
virtualenv = /var/www/my_api/current/my_api_virtualenv
module = wsgi
plugin = python36u
wsgi-file= wsgi.py
uid=svc.my_api
gid=svc.my_api
master = true
processes = 2
enable-threads = true
need-app=true
logto =/var/www/my_api/logs/my_api.log
socket =127.0.0.1:9090
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

And if I run the command `sudo systemctl status uwsgi`

```
● uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-10-19 11:47:01 CEST; 9s ago
 Main PID: 20038 (uwsgi)
   Status: "The Emperor is governing 1 vassals"
   CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi.service
           ├─20038 /usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi.ini
           ├─20039 /usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi.ini
           ├─20040 /usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini my_api.ini
           ├─20043 /usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini my_api.ini
           └─20044 /usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini my_api.ini

Oct 19 11:47:01 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: *** Operational MODE: no-workers ***
Oct 19 11:47:01 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 20038)
Oct 19 11:47:01 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: [emperor-tyrant] dropping privileges to 997 995 for instance my_api.ini
Oct 19 11:47:01 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: *** Stats server enabled on /run/uwsgi/stats.sock fd: 7 ***
Oct 19 11:47:01 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: *** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 7) ***
Oct 19 11:47:01 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from my_api.ini
Oct 19 11:47:03 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: Fri Oct 19 11:47:03 2018 - [emperor] vassal my_api.ini has been spawned
Oct 19 11:47:03 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: Fri Oct 19 11:47:03 2018 - [emperor] vassal my_api.ini is ready to accept requests
Oct 19 11:47:03 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: Fri Oct 19 11:47:03 2018 - [emperor] vassal my_api.ini is now loyal
Oct 19 11:47:03 my_server.local uwsgi[20038]: Fri Oct 19 11:47:03 2018 - [emperor] vassal my_api.ini is now loyal
```

You notice it's working properly without errors, but when I check `htop` I see the following:
[image: output of htop filtered on uwsgi]

So despite the face that I specify `uid` and `gid` in my_app.ini, uwsgi still run the processes as `uwsig`.

When I change those variables

uid = uwsgi
gid = uwsgi

in the main `/etc/uwsgi.ini` to be like

```
uid=svc.my_api
gid=svc.my_api
```

it doesn't work and I get the following output of `sudo systemctl status uwsgi`

```
● uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-10-19 12:03:23 CEST; 309ms ago
 Main PID: 20118 (uwsgi)
   Status: "uWSGI is ready"
   CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi.service
           └─20118 /usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi.ini

Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: *** Operational MODE: no-workers ***
Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 20118)
Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: error removing unix socket, unlink(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 198]
Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 230]
Oct 19 12:03:23 my_server.local uwsgi[20118]: waiting for Emperor death...
```

So my question is: does anyone know why it uwsgi still runs under uwsgi user and how can I make the use `svc.my_app` to own the process of uwsgi?

**UPDATE 23/10/2018 Based on the comment from @Kamil Niski** I tried to run `uWSGI` as root.
When I replaced `uwsgi` with `root` in `/etc/uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
uid = root
gid = root
pidfile = /run/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
emperor = /etc/uwsgi.d
stats = /run/uwsgi/stats.sock
chmod-socket = 660
emperor-tyrant = true
cap = setgid,setuid.
```

It didn't work and I get the following error:

```
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit uwsgi.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Oct 23 14:13:08 my_server.local systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi.service entered failed state.
Oct 23 14:13:08 my_server.local systemd[1]: uwsgi.service failed.
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: uwsgi.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI Emperor Service...
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit uwsgi.service has begun starting up.
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi.ini
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: setting capability setgid [6]
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: setting capability setuid [7]
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17.1 (64bit) on [Tue Oct 23 14:13:09 2018] ***
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) on 09 July 2018 03
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: os: Linux-3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 26 15:12:11 UTC 2018
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: nodename: my_server.local
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: machine: x86_64
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: clock source: unix
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: pcre jit disabled
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: detected number of CPU cores: 2
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: current working directory: /
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: your processes number limit is 15030
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor Service.
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit uwsgi.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: *** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi.service entered failed state.
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: [emperor-tyrant] dropping privileges to 1004 1004 for instance my_api.ini
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: uwsgi.service failed.
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local uwsgi[32290]: cap_set_proc(): Operation not permitted [core/utils.c line 301]
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: uwsgi.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for uwsgi.service
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor Service.
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit uwsgi.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi.service entered failed state.
Oct 23 14:13:09 my_server.local systemd[1]: uwsgi.service failed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to run uWSGI under `svc.my_api` after changing the ownership of the following directories:

`chown -R svc.my_api:svc.my_api /etc/uwsgi.d/`

`chown svc.my_api:svc.my_api /etc/uwsgi.ini`

`chown -R svc.my_api:svc.my_api /run/uwsgi/`

and by editing the `/etc/uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
uid = svc.my_api
gid = svc.my_api
pidfile = /run/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
emperor = /etc/uwsgi.d
stats = /run/uwsgi/stats.sock
chmod-socket = 660
emperor-tyrant = false
cap = setgid,setuid
```

Setting emperor-tyrant to `false` have solved the problem!
Why disabling the emperor-tyrant would solve the problem? Because 
The emperor-tyrant option if it's on as it sets uid/gid for every process based on the owner of the related .ini config file.

Sources:

https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2016/02/10/deploying-python-web-apps-with-nginx-and-uwsgi-emperor/

&

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html#tyrant-mode-secure-multi-user-hosting

Comment: I'm not sure if this what you wanted. But if it solves your problem thats ok. I was guiding you to run emperor process under root user and all vassals as unprivileged user.

Comment: Now the uwsgi proces for `my_app.ini` is run under `svc.my_api` and that's what I needed. But I have to admit that there are a lot of things I don't understand and I feel I have to do some experiments to understand it better. But for now got what I needed! Thanks Kamil

Answer (score 2):

The uwsgi documentation gives you a hint on what might be wrong.

> The emperor is normally run as root, setting the UID and GID in each
>   instance’s config. The vassal instance then drops privileges before
>   serving requests. In this mode, if your users have access to their own
>   uWSGI configuration files, you can’t trust them to set the correct uid
>   and gid. **You could run the emperor as unprivileged user (with uid
>   and gid) but all of the vassals would then run under the same user, as
>   unprivileged users are not able to promote themselves to other
>   users.**

This means you should run emperor as root and then vassals privileges should be dropped as expected.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, but as you see in my my_app.ini file I specify which users the vassal should have (uid and gid) but it still runs as root, while I would expect it wouldn't as described in the documentation

Comment: @Peshmerge But you are not running as root. You show in htop and in `uwsgi.ini` that you are using `uwsgi` user. Emperor has to be running as root not `uwsgi`. Then it will be able to drop privileges correctly.

Comment: I didn't touch the file `/etc/uwsgi.ini`. I will just change it and see what will happen!

Comment: changing the `uid` and `gid` in `/etc/uwsgi.ini` to `root` didn't help stop the uwsgi server. Setting it back to uwsgi makes it work normal!